# How to accepts inputs and store them in prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to design a predicate such which interactively accepts input to create a new student record with an empty class list. Also I need to check that  student is not yet in the system by checking studentID is not in the database.

This is the student database

```
% name, studentId, course list
student(name(jane, [ann]), 5555, ['CS3230'] ).
```

Output should be like this

```
?- addStudent.
Student last name: doe.
Student first name: [jim,k].
Student Id: 23123.
true.
```

Here is my code

```
addStudent :- write('Student last name: '),
          read(L),
          write('Student first name: '),
          read(F),
          write('Student ID: '),
          read(ID),
          assertz(student(name([L,F])),ID,_),
          not(member(ID,student)).
```

I'm getting ERROR: add/3: Undefined procedure: assertz after reading the inputs (after asking the student id)
How do i fix this to work my code?

Comment: I'll bet your error says `assertz/3` not just `assertz`. The problem is you're giving 3 arguments to `assertz/1` which expects just one argument. I suspect you just haven't applied your parentheses properly. Try `assertz(student(name([L,F]),ID,_))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your predicate addStudent, call an intermediate predicate that you define as such:

```
addStudent :-
[...]
read(ID),
insertStd(L,F,ID).

%Case where student exist, will return true and not get to the second predicate%
insertStd(L,F,ID) :- student(name(L,F),ID,_).

%Case where student do not exsist, will insert it to the fact database%
insertStd(L,F,ID) :- assertz(student(L,F),ID,[])).
```

Good luck with the rest of the homework, the questions are not getting easier in this freaking assignment!

A fellow victim of programming paradigms

Comment: Thank You! Haha couldn't agree more with you.

Comment: ERROR: assertz/1: No permission to modify static procedure `student/3'            I'm getting this error. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you add the line 
:- dynamic(student/3). 
on top of your database file?