# Use assertz while within a clause within swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, expert-system

I'm trying to make a modified version of the expert system example within [swi-prolog.org](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/expert_system.pl). I'm trying to modify it to be able to do:

```
good_pet(X) :- bird(X), small(X).
good_pet(X) :- cuddly(X), small(X).
good_pet(X) :- cuddly(X), yellow(X).
```

Without the program reasking if small() or cuddly is true.
I tried doing:

```
:- dynamic ([small/1, cuddly/1 ]).
good_pet(X) :- bird(X), assertz(small(X)).
good_pet(X) :- bird(X), small(X).
good_pet(X) :- assertz(cuddly(X)), assertz(small(X)).
good_pet(X) :- cuddly(X), small(X).
good_pet(X) :- cuddly(X), yellow(X).
```

As expained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742251/how-to-accepts-inputs-and-store-them-in-prolog).
But that ends up giving this error:

```
No permission to access private_procedure `assertz/1'
In:
   [4] clause(assertz(cuddly(tweety)),_1306)
   [3] prove(assertz(cuddly(tweety))) at  line 11
   [2] prove((assertz(...),assertz(...))) at  line 8
   [1] prove(good_pet(tweety)) at  line 12
```

Is there a solution to this error or any another way to save the result of the asked questions?

Comment: Are you using SWISH online?

Comment: @damianodamiano yes, I am using the online version.

Answer (score 1):

The meta-interpreter that you are trying to use does not take into account clauses that call built-in predicates such as `assertz/1`. Try:

```
prove(true) :- !.
prove((B, Bs)) :- !,
    prove(B),
    prove(Bs).
prove(H) :-
    predicate_property(H, built_in),
    !,
    call(H).
prove(H) :-
    clause(H, B),
    prove(B).
prove(H) :-
    askable(H),
    writeln(H),
    read(Answer),
    Answer == yes.
```

Comment: I now get:  No permission to call sandboxed `'$current_module'(_1440,_1442)'. Could that be because I'm using the online version?

Comment: @FrankRidder That sounds like a SWISH issue. Are you using modules in your code?

Comment: No, I'm not using anything that is not in the standard example.